# Passing Optional Arguments in Classic ASP for Stored Procedure

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to run some stored queries in an Access database from an ASP page. I'd like to use an ADO Command object to run the procedure instead of simply sending a string to the database to execute. My trouble is occurring when I try to create the parameters to send to the stored procedure. I'm using the 'CreateParameter' method of the Command object. It takes 5 optional arguments, of which I only want to use two; name and value (arguments 1 and 5 respectively).

I've tried the following approaches to set up the parameters:

1) Using named arguments

```vb
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter name:="name", value:="value"
```

2) Using named arguments inside brackets

```vb
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter(name:="name", value:="value")
```

3) Leaving out optional parameters I don't need

```vb
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter("name", , , , "value")
```

What is a simple way to achieve what I'm trying to do, and why does my syntax fail in these cases? I'm clearly missing something here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support named arguments with or without brackets. All parameters required to pass (specific or blank) for [CreateParameter](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp) method of the Command object.
 
For the section 3 in the question, have a look:

```vb
CreateParameter(
name`[optional],                              <- fits ("name")
type [optional, default = adEmpty],           <- NOT fits (type is not empty)
direction[Optional default = adParamInput],   <- fits (blank)
size [optional default = 0],                  <- NOT fits (at least 5 for "value")
value[optional]                               <- fits ("value")
)
```

So, you should specify at least type and size for a text valued parameter. Direction is `adParamInput` already.

```vb
Const adVarChar = 200 ' From adovbs.inc or Ado TypeLib
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter("name", adVarChar, , 5, "value")
```

Comment: CreateParameter is part of ADO not VBScript.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I said something like that? What's mean `CreateParameter method of the Command object`? What I said about vbscript and arguments is not related to ADO. Just for VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example that can be followed.

http://www.webconcerns.co.uk/asp/accessqueries/accessqueries.asp

see also

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/628368-running-access-stored-queries-parameters

Remember access uses stored queries not stored procedures so some differences apply.  For additional information search for

ASP with Access stored queries using parameters - .net

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that they were only stored queries, not procedures. Do stored procedures give you more flexibility? E.g. PL-SQL?

Comment: The differences are discussed pretty well here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/architecturegeneral/thread/c6864235-5645-4632-93be-15d4d9bd286d/.  You can also search on this: stored procedures vs stored queries